# How can I speed up loading jsonl-files and unest columns that contain dataframes?

Tags: r, json, performance, parallel-processing

I have many very large zip files 100MB to 1GB each. They contain many variables, some of which are nested data frames. The following code downloads and unzips 1 of them.

That works fine for me.

But then two things take a long time: 1. loading the file in R and 2. unnesting the variables that contain data-frames.

Any idea on how to speed things up? On my computer, the part I label PROBLEM AREA below takes about 1 minute and I have a few hundred files that need to go through this process.

I don't know much about parallel processing, unfortunately. Maybe I should use some map()-function instead? Maybe unnesting can be done differently? Maybe the jasonl-file can be loaded differently?

**Warning**: Script downloads a 95 MB .zip file that contains several .jsonl-files. Just in case you don't want to use data or whatever.

```
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(
  here,
  tidyverse,
  janitor,
  jsonlite
)

#----- This segment is just for downloading and unzipping (NOT a problem) -----#

# URL
url <- "https://data.jobtechdev.se/annonser/historiska/monthly/2006_monthly.zip"

# Specify the local directory to save the files (change this to your desired directory)
here()
download_dir <- here("temp")
filename <- "2006_monthly.zip"

# Create the directory if it doesn't exist
if (!dir.exists(download_dir)) {
  dir.create(download_dir)
}

download.file(url, destfile = file.path(download_dir, filename), mode = "wb")
unzip(here("temp", "2006_monthly.zip"), exdir = here("temp"))

#----- PROBLEM AREA -----#

# There are two lines that takes a very long time (# 1 and # 6)

# 1 Load jsonl file
jsonl_data_2006_01 <- stream_in(file(here("temp", "2006_01.jsonl")))

# 2 CheckClean and check col. names
jsonl_data_2006_01 <- jsonl_data_2006_01 |> clean_names()

# 3 Identify columns containing dataframes
dataframe_columns <- sapply(jsonl_data_2006_01, is.data.frame)

# 4 Get the names of the columns containing dataframes
dataframe_column_names <- names(dataframe_columns[dataframe_columns])

# 5 Create a character vector with the names of TRUE columns
true_column_names <- names(dataframe_columns)[dataframe_columns]

# 6 Unnest columns with dataframes in them
jsonl_data_2006_01_unested <-  jsonl_data_2006_01 |> 
  unnest_wider(true_column_names, names_sep = "_")
```

**EDIT:**

I've rewritten the code into a function and so that it uses here() instead of relative paths: works great.

```
# LOAD LIBRARIES
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(

  here, # Relative paths
  tidyverse,
  duckdb,
  jsonlite
)

# CODE:

import_jsonl_data <- function(select_cols) {
  # here()
  test <- here::here("data", "dbdata", "2006_*.jsonl")
  duckdb_import_query <- paste0("SELECT ", select_cols, " FROM read_json_auto('", test, "');")
  
  # Start DuckDB in-memory database and load the json extension
  con <- dbConnect(duckdb())
  dbExecute(con, "INSTALL json; LOAD json;")
  
  # Load all *.jsonl files and return a data.frame with all structures flattened
  result <- dbGetQuery(con, duckdb_import_query)
  
  # Close the connection
  dbDisconnect(con, shutdown=TRUE)
  
  return(result)
}

# Test:

data_frame_2006 <- import_jsonl_data(select_cols)
```

Comment: Do you need to load everything? Do all thse json files share the same schema? Have you consider, evaluated or open for options like duckdb or arrow?

Comment: It's under development and not on CRAN, but the **yyjsonr** package (https://github.com/coolbutuseless/yyjsonr) seems to have some good performance when it comes to reading JSON files.

Comment: @margusl I don't know what those are, but I need the final data in one dataframe in the end.

Comment: @HenrikB Will look at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using DuckDB for loading all 2006 files (zip extracted to
`2006_monthly/`, 12 files in total, ranging from ~35Mb to ~75Mb) and flattening the resulting structure took less than 5 seconds, it can probably be improved (e.g. defining columns during import and not relying on `read_json_auto()` magic). The following example returns single `data.frame` as requested in comments, though it would make sense to store it in duckdb database and perhaps do most of the analytics in duckdb, either through SQL or [dbplyr](https://duckdb.org/docs/api/r.html#dbplyr) . This would allow working with a larger-than-memory dataset, if needed (resulting `data.frame` was 376.6 Mb, 245227 rows / 83 columns).

One assumption here was that all files use the same JSON schema (structure and column names are extracted from the first line of the first file). And max depth of the nested structure is assumed to be 2.

First section basically builds a SQL query to get every column, either from from top level or from nested structures. For that we parse a single JSON object (a line from the first file), feed it through `purrr::list_flatten()` to get a list of flat names (i.e. `application_details.email`), for every column name with a `.` we append a valid output column name (i.e. `AS application_details_email`), otherwise we'd get columns with just inner structure names (`email`).

```r
library(duckdb)
#> Loading required package: DBI

# get a sample row fron ndjson to build a DuckDB SQL query to 
# extract all fields from nested structs
json_sample <- 
  readLines("2006_monthly/2006_01.jsonl", n = 1) |> 
  jsonlite::parse_json()
str(json_sample)
#> List of 34
#>  $ access              : NULL
#>  $ access_to_own_car   : NULL
#>  $ application_deadline: chr "2006-01-27"
#>  $ application_details :List of 6
#>   ..$ email      : NULL
#>   ..$ information: NULL
#>  ...

json_fields <- purrr::list_flatten(json_sample, name_spec = "{outer}.{inner}") |> names()
str(json_fields)
#>  chr [1:83] "access" "access_to_own_car" "application_deadline" ...

# set output column names for lower deeper level fields, i.e "application_details.email AS application_details_email"
nested_idx <- grep("\\.", json_fields)
json_fields[nested_idx] <- paste(json_fields[nested_idx], gsub(".", "_", json_fields[nested_idx], fixed = TRUE), sep = " AS ")
str(json_fields)
#>  chr [1:83] "access" "access_to_own_car" "application_deadline" ...

select_cols <- paste(json_fields, collapse = ", ")
str(select_cols)
#>  chr "access, access_to_own_car, application_deadline, application_details.email AS application_details_email, applic"| __truncated__

duckdb_import_query <- paste0("SELECT ",select_cols," FROM read_json_auto('2006_monthly/*.jsonl');")
str(duckdb_import_query)
#>  chr "SELECT access, access_to_own_car, application_deadline, application_details.email AS application_details_email,"| __truncated__

# start DuckDB in-memory database, load json extension
con <- dbConnect(duckdb())
dbExecute(con, "INSTALL json; LOAD json;")
#> [1] 0

# start the timer 
tictoc::tic("SELECT ... FROM read_json_auto('2006_monthly/*.jsonl');")
# load all *.jsonl files and return a data.frame with all structures flattened
y2006 <- dbGetQuery(con, duckdb_import_query)
tictoc::toc()
#> SELECT ... FROM read_json_auto('2006_monthly/*.jsonl');: 4.63 sec elapsed

# close connection
dbDisconnect(con, shutdown=TRUE)
```

Resulting frame:

```r
str(y2006)
#> 'data.frame':    245227 obs. of  83 variables:
#>  $ access                                   : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ access_to_own_car                        : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ application_deadline                     : Date, format: "2006-01-27" "2006-01-18" ...
#>  $ application_details_email                : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ application_details_information          : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ application_details_other                : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ application_details_reference            : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ application_details_url                  : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ application_details_via_af               : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ description_company_information          : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ description_conditions                   : chr  "Heltid/deltid, vikariat tom 2006-12-31" "Tjänsten är på 100%. I första hand vikariat under vårterminen, ev förlängning." "Tillsvidareanställning. 20-25 timmar/månad. 1-2 tjänstgöringshelger/månad ingår i arbetsschemat." "Heltid, vikariat på 1 år." ...
#>  $ description_needs                        : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ description_requirements                 : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ description_text                         : chr  "Handikapp & Habilitering, Habiliteringscenter Täby för barn och ungdom  Habiliteringscenter Täby för barn arbet"| __truncated__ "Skolhagenskolan i Täby kyrkby söker omgående lärare i Svenska och Engelska för årskurserna 6-9. Tjänsten är ett"| __truncated__ "Verksamhetsbeskrivning\r\nInside & Living är en inredningsbutik med dansk design. Vi har möbler, presentartikla"| __truncated__ "Då vår sekreterare ska vara mammaledig söker vi nu en vikarie.  Arbetsuppgifterna består bl a av: - Utskrifter "| __truncated__ ...
#>  $ description_text_formatted               : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ driving_license                          : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ driving_license_required                 : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ duration_concept_id                      : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ duration_label                           : chr  "Tills vidare" "3-6 månader" "Tills vidare" "Längre än 6 månader" ...
#>  $ duration_legacy_ams_taxonomy_id          : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ employer_email                           : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ employer_name                            : chr  "STOCKHOLMS LÄNS SJUKVÅRDSOMRÅDE" "Skolhagenskolan" "Inside & Living" "InvestFakta AB" ...
#>  $ employer_organization_number             : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ employer_phone_number                    : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ employer_url                             : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ employer_workplace                       : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ employment_type_concept_id               : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ employment_type_label                    : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ employment_type_legacy_ams_taxonomy_id   : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ experience_required                      : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ external_id                              : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ headline                                 : chr  "LOGOPED, vikariat" "Lärare i Svenska och Engelska, årskurs 6-9" "Inredningssäljare" "Administratör/Sekreterare" ...
#>  $ id                                       : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ last_publication_date                    : Date, format: "2006-01-27" "2006-01-18" ...
#>  $ logo_url                                 : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ must_have_languages                      : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ must_have_skills                         : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ must_have_work_experiences               : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ nice_to_have_languages                   : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ nice_to_have_skills                      : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ nice_to_have_work_experiences            : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ number_of_vacancies                      : num  1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 ...
#>  $ occupation_concept_id                    : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ occupation_label                         : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ occupation_legacy_ams_taxonomy_id        : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#>  $ occupation_field_concept_id              : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ occupation_field_label                   : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ occupation_field_legacy_ams_taxonomy_id  : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ occupation_group_concept_id              : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ occupation_group_label                   : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ occupation_group_legacy_ams_taxonomy_id  : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ publication_date                         : Date, format: "2006-01-10" "2006-01-11" ...
#>  $ removed                                  : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ removed_date                             : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ salary_description                       : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ salary_type_concept_id                   : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ salary_type_label                        : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ salary_type_legacy_ams_taxonomy_id       : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ scope_of_work_max                        : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ scope_of_work_min                        : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ source_type                              : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ timestamp                                : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ webpage_url                              : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ working_hours_type_concept_id            : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ working_hours_type_label                 : chr  "Heltid/Deltid" "Heltid" "Deltid" "Heltid" ...
#>  $ working_hours_type_legacy_ams_taxonomy_id: chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ workplace_address_city                   : chr  "--" "TÄBY" NA "TÄBY" ...
#>  $ workplace_address_coordinates            : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ workplace_address_country                : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ workplace_address_country_code           : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ workplace_address_country_concept_id     : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ workplace_address_municipality           : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ workplace_address_municipality_code      : chr  "0160" "0160" "0160" "0160" ...
#>  $ workplace_address_municipality_concept_id: chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ workplace_address_postcode               : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ workplace_address_region                 : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ workplace_address_region_code            : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ workplace_address_region_concept_id      : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ workplace_address_street_address         : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ other_old_legacy_attributes_ARBETSDRIFT  : chr  "Dagtid" "Dagtid" "Schemalagd arbetstid" "Dagtid" ...
#>  $ other_old_legacy_attributes_DXA          : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ other_old_legacy_attributes_BIL_KRAV     : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ other_old_legacy_attributes_TILLTRADE    : chr  NA NA "Omgående" NA ...

format(object.size(y2006), units = "auto")
#> [1] "376.6 Mb"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Not sure if you saw my comment earlier but I made a mistake. The code works great. Thank you very much. Duckdb for the win!

Comment: I did :) Glad you got it sorted.

Comment: I did run into 1 problem I couldn't fix. Mind me asking for advice? I can start a new post if you wish. The error is:

Comment: y2012 <- dbGetQuery(con, duckdb_import_query)
Error: rapi_execute: Failed to run query
Error: Invalid Input Error: JSON transform error in file "C:\...\2012_09.jsonl", in line 1487: Failed to cast value to numerical: ""
Try increasing 'sample_size', reducing 'maximum_depth', specifying 'columns', 'format' or 'records' manually, setting 'ignore_errors' to true, or setting 'union_by_name' to true when reading multiple files with a different structure. 

It does works when I use: stream_in(file(here("data","raw", "2012_01.jsonl"))) OR stream_i

Comment: Without seeing that exact file it's hard to guess. Are you using the same column list as for 2016 or are you rebuilding it for every year? And does it fail the same way with something like `dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM read_json_auto('2012_09.jsonl');")` ?

Comment: No that seems to work(!). What's the difference?

Comment: Also, how can I change this line : 

duckdb_import_query <- paste0("SELECT ",select_cols," FROM read_json_auto('2006_monthly/*.jsonl');")

Should I remove select_cols maybe?

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM ...` returns all imported colmns, meaning that you'll have a nested data.frame, `select_cols` includes existing and extractable columns from one of the jsons, but if it lists something that is not present in imported file, there's an error (though I would have assumed it fails with some different message).  You can try to build `select_cols` on that offending file as it was done with `2006_01.jsonl` in my example, comparing `select_cols` might also give you some insights on changes.

Comment: I would also try to load all files, like all years: when you have extracted all zips to `raw` and have `raw/2006/*.jsonl`, `raw/2007/*.jsonl` etc, you can use `read_json_auto('raw/*/*.jsonl` in duckdb query. Though I'd rather not do that with in-memory instance and directly to data.frame but something along the lines of `con <- dbConnect(duckdb(), dbdir = "my-db.duckdb", read_only = FALSE); dbGetQuery(con, "CREATE TABLE json_import AS SELECT * FROM read_json_auto('raw/*/*.jsonl');");` to load all files into `json_import` table stored in `my-db.duckdb` file.

Comment: ... and then query that `json_import` table, first with something simple like `dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM json_import LIMIT 10;")`,  then with flattining query like `paste0("SELECT ",select_cols," FROM json_import;")` ; but as said, without seeing that file / checking differences it's just guesswork. Those debugging steps might reveal something. Or might not.